# How to get the class library of .Net Framework in visual studio?

Tags: c#, .net, class

In case of java we have and API to find the information about the predefined classes and we can learn all the methods in those classes and the whole structure of the Java classes can be known by it and we can download an offline version so that we can use the browser and we can carry on the learning process. My question is that how can we do the same thing when we are using the .Net Framework and how can we use visual studio to view these defined classes?

Answer (score 1):

Use the MSDN. It is online at http://www.msdn.com or you can install the local help collection on your computer for offline browsing. Check out the visual studio help menu.

To get help on a specific class or method, simply place the cursor on it and press F1.

Answer (score 1):

When you install the visiual studio in your system after the complete installation of visiual studio you are offered to to install Help document, when you intall VS you should intall the Help documentation in your system also and then you can get help locally from Visial studio local help menu and can read about all its API

Hope it help :)